# launch many transactions typeorm into loop javascript

Tags: electron, typeorm

*In my Electron App I would like to inject data (like Fixtures) when App launched.*

I use typeorm library for managing my SQLite3 Database connection.

I created json file that represent Entity typeorm and I would like persist all of them in my DB with typeorm. For that It seems that use trasaction is more efficient.

I try two differents things but the result is the same and I don't uderstand why. The issue message is :

> Error: Transaction already started for the given connection, commit
>   current transaction before starting a new one

**My first implementation of transaction** :

```
async setAll(entity, data)
{
    let connection = await this.init()
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner()
    await queryRunner.connect()

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data))
    {
        await typeorm.getManager().transaction(transactionalEntityManager =>
        {

        })
    }
}
```

**My second implementation of transaction** :

```
async setAll(entity, data)
{
    let connection = await this.init()
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner()
    await queryRunner.connect()

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data))
    {
        let genre1 = new Genre()
        genre1.name = 'toto'
        genre1.identifier = 'gt'
        genre1.logo = ''
        genre1.isActivate = false

        await queryRunner.startTransaction()
        await queryRunner.manager.save(genre1)
        await queryRunner.commitTransaction()
        await queryRunner.release()
    }
}
```

*NB : The second implementation persist correctly the first object but not the others.*

**How can manage many typeorm Transaction created into loop for persist lot of data ?**

Answer (score 1):

```
async setAll(entity, data) {
    let connection = await this.init()
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner()
    await queryRunner.connect()
    await queryRunner.startTransaction()
    try {
        for await (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
            let genre1 = new Genre()
            genre1.name = 'toto'
            genre1.identifier = 'gt'
            genre1.logo = ''
            genre1.isActivate = false
          const newGenre= queryRunner.manager.create(Genre,genre1)
           await queryRunner.manager.save(newGenre)
        }

        await queryRunner.commitTransaction()
    } catch {
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction()
    } finally {
        await queryRunner.release()
    }
```